# Joomla: List with custom fields

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am trying to create a list of open bids similar to the one on this site run by the city of Worcester, Massachusetts:

http://www.worcesterma.gov/e-services/bids/open-bids

How would I create this type of list in Joomla?

Comment: @Oded: I really don't think that a site run by the city of Worcester, Massachusetts, qualifies as spam.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the data is structured and input into the system, easytable may be an option:

[Extension Link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/tables-a-lists/10415?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czo3OiJ0YWJ1bGFyIjt9) /  [Demo Site](http://j15ref.craigphillips.biz/easy-tables.html)